# Why can't I use substitution to find $y$-intercept?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question, where the gradient, and a point are given.

The gradient is $m=-4/3$, and the point given is $(3/2,3)$

Let $c$ be the $y$-intercept

$y=mx+c$

$y=(-4/3)x + c$

If I substitute $x$ and $y$ from the point given, 
$3=(-4/3)(3/2) + c$
and look for $c$, I get $c=5$

But according to my answer sheet, $c=33/8$ by using $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$

Why are the two methods giving different answers?

Maybe there is something obvious that I didn't notice, but I'm really confused. Can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

The answer sheet is wrong. Using $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, we get $y-3=(-4/3)(x-3/2)$. Distributing the $-4/3$, we get $y-3=(-4/3)x+4/2=(-4/3)x+2$. Now add three to both sides, and we get $y=(-4/3)x+5$, so $c=5$ again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone flipped the gradient at some point. If you use $-\frac{3}{4}$ as the gradient, you end up with $c=\frac{33}{8}$.